# Collapsing and Expanding SplitContainer panels

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I have 3 split containers in my winform application. `splitContainer1, splitContainer2, splitContainer3`

*splitContainer1* is the main split container. in it's *panel1* I put *splitContainer2* and in its *panel2* I have *splitContainer3*

I then added two buttons to collapse/hide *splitContainer3* panels: whenever I click on a button, it gets collapsed, but when I want 2 panels be collapsed, one of them automatically gets **expanded again** What can be the problem?

```
private void btToggleCI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (splitContainer3.Panel1Collapsed)
    {
        case false:

            splitContainer3.Panel1Collapsed = true;
            btToggleCI.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

            break;

        case true:

            splitContainer3.Panel1Collapsed = false;
            btToggleCI.ForeColor = Color.Black;

            break;
    }
}

private void btToggleTestPlan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (splitContainer3.Panel2Collapsed)
    {
        case false:

            splitContainer3.Panel2Collapsed = true;
            btToggleTestPlan.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

            break;

        case true:

            splitContainer3.Panel2Collapsed = false;
            btToggleTestPlan.ForeColor = Color.Black;

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A SplitContainerControl can have up to one panel collapsed.

You can't collapse both panels simultaneously (what would that look like?).

Comment: Damn! haha...So what would be the workaround? I want when both buttons are pressed the splitcontainer somehow be vanished! any ideas?

Comment: @Sean87: `.Visible = false`?